# Detectar \ en Regex

Tags: python, regex

Estoy intentando usar RegEx para detectar qué strings son válidos y cuales no. Debería detectar que los válidos son los que contienen ">":

```
import re

strings = [
"\cf1 06:20 > 50 FF 00 11 9F", "\cf1 06:20 > 50 FE 00 11 A0",
"\cf1 06:20 > 50 FE 00 11 A0", "\cf1 06:20 > 50 FE 00 11 A0",
"\cf2 06:20 < 50 FE 00 00 B1", "\cf2 06:20 < 50 FC 00 00 B3",
"\cf1 06:23 > 50 E5 1F 1F 8C", "\cf2 06:23 < 50 E8 00 00 C7",
"\cf2 06:22 < 50 F1 00 00 BE", "\cf1 06:22 > 50 F2 01 22 9A"
]

for i in strings:
    print(bool(re.match('^\\cf1 [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} > .. ([\dA-F]{2} ){3}([\dA-F]{2})$',i)))
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente error:

```
re.error: bad escape \c at position 1
```

No he logrado poder detectar cuando hay una "\" seguido de un carácter. Entiendo que lo que detecta mal es el principio del validador.

Comment: No te sirve preguntar si el texto contiene un "<" ? De esta forma: if "<" in tuTexto

Comment: Lo que dice chona es más rápido, mas sencillo y más claro que usar regex. Hay algo más que estés validando además de la presencia del < que requiera el uso de expresiones regulares?